# html canvas element blinking and then bugging out

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to have asteroids moving across the screen for a game. The first few asteroids work and then each asteroid will start blinking and bugging out to the point where they won't move across the screen. The variables acx and acy are the x and y coordinates for the asteroids respectively.

```
setInterval(throwAsteroid1A, 5000); 

function throwAsteroid1A() {
    var asteroidCanvas = document.getElementById('asteroidCanvas');
    var context = asteroidCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var acx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200); 
    var acy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); 
    setInterval( () => {
        asteroid.onload = function() {
           context.drawImage(asteroid, asx, asy, aswidth, asheight, acx, acy, 20, 20); 
           acx += 1;
           acy += 1;
       }
       asteroid.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/WfQKE6T.png';
       }, 10)  
       setInterval(asteroidPath, 50)
}
function asteroidPath() {
    // let computedStyle = getComputedStyle(canvasDisplay)
    var asteroidCanvas = document.getElementById('asteroidCanvas');
    let ctx = asteroidCanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(acx,acy, canvasDisplay.width, canvasDisplay.height);

}
```

Comment: At each `setInterval(throwAsteroid1A, 5000)` it's calling `function throwAsteroid1A()` and in that method it's calling `setInterval( () => {....`. Could it all be building up into some humongous everything trying to call everything else?

Comment: That's possible. I think it's definitely something wrong with the `throwAsteroid1A` function. Do you know of another way I could draw my image and move it across the screen without the second setInterval above? Thanks

Comment: I tried requestAnimationFrame and for some reason that wouldn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's obviously something conceptually wrong with your approach. I think the blinking is caused by a timing issue in-between the numerous individual interval timers you set up. The callback function `asteroidPath()` clears a part of the canvas and this might happen at the same time a new Asteroid has been added to the screen - which will delete it either entirely or partly depending on it's screen position.

To work around it you should:

- keep a list of all asteroid objects
- clear the screen completely **once**
- update all asteroid's at once - not each one with it's own timer

So an example based on your code might look a little something like this (just click 'Run code snippet'):

```js
Asteroid = function() {
  this.acx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
  this.acy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  this.image = new Image();
  this.image.onload = function(e) {
    this.loaded = true;
    this.aswidth = e.target.naturalWidth;
    this.asheight = e.target.naturalHeight;
  }
  this.image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/WfQKE6T.png';
}

var asteroidCanvas = document.getElementById('asteroidCanvas');
var context = asteroidCanvas.getContext('2d');
let asteroids = [];

function spawnAsteroid() {
  asteroids.push(new Asteroid());
}

function updateCanvas() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, asteroidCanvas.width, asteroidCanvas.height);
  let asteroid;
  for (let a = 0; a < asteroids.length; a++) {
    asteroid = asteroids[a];
    if (asteroid.image.loaded) {

      context.drawImage(asteroid.image, 0, 0, asteroid.image.aswidth, asteroid.image.asheight, asteroid.acx, asteroid.acy, 20, 20);
      asteroid.acx += 1;
      asteroid.acy += 1;
    }
  }
}
setInterval(spawnAsteroid, 2000);
setInterval(updateCanvas, 50);
spawnAsteroid();
```

```html
<canvas id="asteroidCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Looks good, and now you can use requestAnimationFrame! Also, I would keep a frame counter so you only need one interval being called instead of two.

Comment: @Kokodoko - yeah, there's definitely still room for improvement. ;)

Comment: @zfin No problem - glad I could help! =) By the way, if you think this is the correct answer please consider accepting it using the 'tick' button.